# Python OpenCV stream video error in executable

Tags: python, opencv, video-streaming, opencv3.0

In my python application I'm using OpenCV, among other things, to stream a Video from an IP camera:

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture("http://usr:psw@192.168.1.1/video.cgi")
```

and everithing works fine.

But i needed to obtain an executable, and so I used `PyInstaller`. In the resulting `.exe` the stream doesn't work anymore.

Instead if I change the capture with this:

```
# works with camera_num = 0 (pc's webcam) and = 1 (external USB webcam)
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(camera_num)
```

capturing from webcam of my pc, or with and external USB webcam, everything works.

Any suggestions?

Comment: WHat is the value of `camera_num`?

Comment: @Stiffy2000 almost guaratneed to be 0

Comment: Are you including FFMPEG DLL or something through your IDE that you need when you run the exectuable?

Comment: @Stiffy2000 works with 0 (the integrated webcam) and even with 1 if I attach an external USB camera

Comment: @GPPK no, i'm not. I think that PyInstaller does that automatically. I think that without the FFMPEG dll it shouldn't works even with the webcam...

Comment: @luke88 Not necessarily, that's just one of [many different backends](https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.0/d4/d15/group__videoio__flags__base.html#ga023786be1ee68a9105bf2e48c700294d).

Comment: Also, FFMPEG is not a hard dependency, it's treated more as a plugin and loaded only if it exists when it's needed. As such, automated analysis of the DLL dependencies won't pick it up (you can try it out with the Dependency Walker). You will need to explicitly specify it for inclusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @GPPK and @Dan Mašek comments I could solve the problem.

The problem was, like @Dan Mašek said, that "FFMPEG is not a hard dependency".

So a solution is to search the OpenCV's FFMPEG dll. Launch `python` from the cosnole:

```
# import OpenCV module
import cv2
# retrieve the pathname of the file from which the module was loaded
cv2.__file__
```

the output should be something like:

```
'C:\\Users\\luke\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\lib\\site-packages\\cv2\\cv2.cp36-win_amd64.pyd'
```

go to the `cv2` folder, search for `opencv_ffmpeg340_64.dll` and copy it to the python application's folder.

Now we have to tell `PyInstaller` to add this dll to the `.exe`:

```
pyinstaller -F --add-data "opencv_ffmpeg340_64.dll;." test.py
```

Answer (score 0):

same problem is faced to me in c++. I installed gstream,ffmpeg and opencv-python firstly after rebuild opencv and i solved this problem. Maybe you can use same method for python.